# android set name for incoming call programmatically

Tags: android

How to set name for incoming call?

The contact numbers are present in my App, if someone is calling I want to set name for that incoming call connection.

any suggestion how can this be achieved?

I know this should be possible https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/telecom#integrateCalling

Any github example would be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

You need to intercept the call and overlay the screen with a costume screen that will contain the name from your app according to that number .

You have to register a `BroadcastReceiver` for the action `android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE`

The receiving intent will have a variable `TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING` which will have the current state and `TelephonyManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER` which will have the number calling